# How to relate an opportunity field to an opportunity team member?

Tags: automation

I have a checkbox field on the Opportunity labeled SC Assigned. I want it to be marked True whenever a Pre-Sales Consultant is added on the Opportunity Team Member related list. I tried using a basic workflow but Opportunity Team Member is not a child of the Opportunity so I couldn't get it to work. I believe I need to use an apex trigger to update the Opportunity.SC_Assigned field as True whenever an Opportunity Team Member whose role = Pre-Sales Consultant is added.

What's the most simple way to do this?

Comment: give more information at your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Process Builder as DML create/update events on `OTM` can be handled. `OTM` is a direct child of Opportunity and Process Builder can update a field in the parent Opportunity. A Trigger is unnecessary

Workflow is not an option because you can't update related records.

here's a simple Process Flow where if the OTM Team Role is Channel Manager, update the parent `Opportunity.NextStep` to say "new channel mgr"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried process builder already and it wasn't able to grab the correct fields..

Category of "junction objects" (between User and Opportunity) and docs say email alerts aren't supported on junction objects.

Workflows don't work on OpportunityTeamMember (the option is both inaccessible from GUI as well as forced creation of OpportunityTeamMember.workflow file fails in Eclipse).

Comment: @JonBarker - edited my answer; I'm not seeing why you need junction records